# Java: differences between run and debug (cause of JTextField)

Tags: java, swing, debugging, jtextfield

I'm doing a simple java application for the management of my passwords. I wrote this part of the program:

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame jf = new JFrame("Ttile");
        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        jp.setLayout(null);

        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setSize(1000,1000);
        jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton jb = new JButton("Button");
        jb.setBounds(0,0,120,35);

        JTextField jtf = new JTextField(30);
        jtf.setBounds(100,100,120,30);

        jp.add(jb);
        jp.add(jtf);
        jf.getContentPane().add(jp);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I instantiate a JTextField (just this component) the window (or better, the JPanel) doesn't show any other component in run mode, meanwhile in debug mode it works properly. Is it caused by my video card? Or it's just a problem with the current version of Netbeans/Java? I'm confused cause I cannot understand the reason :S.

Note: if I expand the window to fullscreen every component is visible.. Why this initial issue?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Call `setVisible()` last.

Comment: oups, I missed it. But it is not the main problem. When I instantiate the JTextField, every other component, the button called jb too, are not shown

Comment: Please have a look at the Oracle Swing tutorial, in particular here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/start/HelloWorldSwingProject/src/start/HelloWorldSwing.java

Comment: `Why this initial issue?` - You have already been given the reason. You need to invoke setVisible(...) AFTER all components have been added to the GUI. This will invoke the layout manager, otherwise the panel will have a size of (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint. When you resize the frame the layout manager is invoked automatically, so the components get painted. Also, you should NOT be using a null layout. Use layout managers which is the way Swing was designed to be used.

Comment: Oh right..  now it works, thanks a lot!. However I use a null layout because I can use the method .setBounds as I want, just to move my componet freely in the window. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Using a null layout is the worst thing you can do. You code just contains magic numbers that have no meaning. You have no idea how big each component should be. What if you change the font, then the size of the component needs to change. You should be using [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). I suggest you bookmark the tutorial. You've already been given two links to the tutorial. The tutorial is what you should be using the learn Swing basics. Using an IDE is NOT the way to learn to code Swing.

Comment: Understood, i hope i will learn something ;)

Answer (score 1):

`setVisible(true)` should be the last thing you do. Adding components dynamically (that is, after that call) will require you to revalidate the component hierarchy (else you get what you just saw).